# RobotFramework - Selenium - IEDriver - Jenkins - Remote desktop Windows - Session - Problem

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, robotframework, remote-desktop, selenium-iedriver

RobotFramework selenium tests using IEDriver don't start when called from jenkins on Windows remote desktop. Internet Explorer browser is opening, but redirect does not occur.
[image]

There is message displayed:
This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.

The proces freezes on jenkins:
[image]

The situation is werid, because when I log to remote desktop physically and start session and launch tests from jenkins, then IE browser is opening and redirect occurs.

**init**.robot file:

```
*** Keywords ***
My Setup
    ${ieOptions}=   Create Dictionary   ignoreProtectedModeSettings=${True}    ignoreZoomLevel=${True}    ignoreZoomSetting=${True}
    Set To Dictionary   ${ieOptions}  se:ieOptions  ${ieOptions}
    Create WebDriver    Ie    executable_path=${EXECDIR}/driver/IEDriverServer_32.exe    desired_capabilities=${ieOptions}
```

Server Manager properties:
[image]

I tried to use PhantomJS to execute tests using IE headless mode, but PhantomJS is deprecated and this solution didn't work. I've also tried to deploy tests on standalone way but it didn't work. I've also tried deploying tests on Microsoft Edge with internet explorer mode, but it also didn't work:

```
${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER  sys, selenium.webdriver
Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   ignoreProtectedModeSettings    ${True}
Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   ignoreZoomLevel    ${True}
Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   ignoreZoomSetting    ${True}
Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   nativeEvents    ${False}
Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   EdgeExecutablePath    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
Create WebDriver    Ie    executable_path=${EXECDIR}/driver/IEDriverServer_32.exe    desired_capabilities=${dc}
```